# Probability, that the computer network will work

Tags: probability

So a single computer blows up after turning it on with probability $0.05$. We have an order to create a network of $50$ computers, and we gathered $52$ computers for this purpose. What's the probability, that we can create a network with these computers?

My solution:

So in order to work either $50$ computers are good and $2$ are faulty, $51$ are good and $1$ is faulty or $52$ are good.

Therefore the probability is:

${{52}\choose{50}}(0.95)^{50}*(0.05)^2+{{52}\choose{51}}(0.95)^{50}*(0.05)^1+0.95^{52} \approx 0.5$

Now how many computers do I need, for the probability to be $\approx 0.99$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is fine.  To answer the $0.99$ question, you need to increase $52$ and repeat the calculation until the probability gets that high.

To reduce the calculation, you can reason that if the odds are only $0.01$ that less than $50$ computers are working, the chance of less than $49$ working is negligible.  Then you can solve ${50+n \choose 49}0.95^{49}\cdot 0.05^{n+1}=0.01$  You can just plug this into a spreadsheet or use bisection with a calculator.  $n$ came out higher than I expected.